# How to express iteration process in uml.sequence-diagram

Tags: uml

In the following picture I have two directional realationship between '**Master**' and '**Slave**' (**Client** - **Server** if you wish).

The Master sends a command 'Request' and the slave responds "***I am not ready yet. Ask again later***". Then after certain amount of time the Master queries again, and if the Slave is not ready will return the same message. This process may repeat undefined times.

How to express that iteration in a sequence diagram?

Here is an example of one interaction pair(Request - Response):

[image]

Comment: See http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html#operator-loop

Comment: @xmojmr
If you had put it as an answer, I would have accepted it as valid. For now I can just upvote :) Thank you!

Comment: I did not notice the comment :-/ However, @xmojmr often just references uml-diagrams for good reason ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will simply use a loop fragment like this:

[image]

The loop condition is placed in square brackets top left of the frame.

Comment: Just to represent the requirement (as it is not clear enough on the OP's diagrams and you've apparently used it as a base) - the loop condition can be something like [Slave is not ready] .

Comment: @Ister Yes, instead of a "do n times" you can also put any boolean condition in the loop guard. There's also a `break` fragment that can be placed in between the messages.